# Mapping One Observable to Another Observable of a Different Type in UniRX

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reactive-programming

I'm working in Unity in C# using the UniRX plugin. For those not familiar with it UniRX is an implementation of the C# Reactive extension ported back into C# .Net 2 (which is what unity uses as of version 5.3.5).
What I'm trying to do is take data from one IObservable in type A convert it using a System.Func and automatically post the result in a new IObservable of type B. I wrote a few lines of code to do this but I feel like this should be something that is just automatically included in the Reactive extension (but I just couldn't find the correct method to call in the documentation).
The code I wrote is as follows:

```
private class ObserverableBridge<TIn, TOut> {
    public ReactiveProperty<TOut> outStream;

    public ObserverableBridge(IObservable<TIn> input, System.Func<TIn, TOut> converter) {
        this.outStream = new ReactiveProperty<TOut>();
        input.Subscribe((inValue) => this.outStream.Value = converter(inValue));
    }
}

public static IObservable<TOut> Bridge<TIn, TOut>(this IObservable<TIn> a, System.Func<TIn, TOut> converter) {
    return new ObserverableBridge<TIn, TOut>(a, converter).outStream;
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
        ReactiveProperty<float> input = new ReactiveProperty<float>(0.1f);
        IObservable <int> output = input.Bridge((inFloat) => Mathf.RoundToInt(inFloat));
        output.Subscribe((a) => { Debug.Log("a = " + a); });
        for(int i = 1; i<3; i++) {
            input.Value = i + 0.1f;
        }
```

And produces output like:

```
a = 0
a = 1
a = 2
```

What I'm curious about is there a way to do this built into the Reactive Extension (seems to me like there should be) so that I don't need to use my own Bridge system.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Select()`:

```cs
ReactiveProperty<float> input = new ReactiveProperty<float>(0.1f);
input.Select<float, int>(Mathf.RoundToInt).Subscribe(a => Debug.LogFormat("a = {0}", a));
```